# How to let a script run for all subfolders in the chosen directory via Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I have written a script to convert and resize pictures for a project. It converts and resizes for the directory set, but I also want to cover the files in the subdirectorys. How could I let this script run for all subdirectorys in the chosen directory?

```
$refdate = (Get-Date).AddDays(-1).Date
$dir = "DIRECTORY"

<# Converting .jpg to .webp #>
<# Deletes all .webp files of recently changed .jpg files #>
$jpegs   = (Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter '*.jpg' -File | Where-Object { $_.CreationTime -gt $refdate }).BaseName
Get-ChildItem -Path $dir -Filter '*.webp' -File | Where-Object { $jpegs -contains $_.BaseName } | Remove-Item

<# Creates .webp files for all .jpg files in the directory that don't have a corresponding .jpg file #>
$images = Get-ChildItem -File $dir\*.jpg, $dir\*.webp |
            Group-Object { $_.BaseName } |
              Where-Object { $_.Group.Extension -notcontains '.webp' } |
                ForEach-Object Group

foreach ($img in $images) {

    
    $outputName = $img.DirectoryName + "\" + $img.BaseName + ".webp"

    cwebp.exe $img.Fullname -o $outputName
}

<# Generating thumbnails 
<# Removes all thumbnails from .webp images that have been edited in the last 24 hours #> 
Get-ChildItem $dir\*.webp -Exclude *-thumb.webp -File | 
            Where-Object CreationTime -gt $refdate | 
                ForEach-Object { $_.Fullname -replace '\.webp$', '-thumb.webp' } | Remove-Item

<# Generates resized thumbnail based on if a .webp has already been resized #>
$width = 145
$heigth = 204
$voorbeeld = Get-ChildItem -File $dir\*.webp |
                Where-Object {$_.Name -notmatch "-thumb" -and -not(Test-Path ($_.FullName -replace ".webp","-thumb.webp"))}

Set-Location -Path $dir
$size = -join($width, "x",$heigth)
foreach($image in $voorbeeld) {

$baseName = $image.BaseName
$extension = $image.Extension
$outputName = $baseName + "-thumb" + $extension
convert $image.name -resize $size $outputName
```

}

Comment: for the chose directory in `$dir`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Get-ChildItem` you can use the `-Recurse` parameter to go through all child locations specified.

More information in the PowerShell documentation,

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-7.1

Comment: Thanks! That helped me with Get-Childitem. Is there a way to do the same thing for ImageMagick (the last part of the code)?

Comment: What do you mean by this? In your Get-Children call, and the loop, you put your code you need to execute in the loop. This is a common practice. The ImageMagick is just an executable. Calling/Running executables via PowerShell is a well documented/talked about use case. See the MS answer here: [• PowerShell: Running Executables](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/7703.powershell-running-executables.aspx). There are many ImageMagic Q&A on SO. [See:](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=ImageMagick+)